# Tooltips of GTK applications are unreadable within KDE

Tags: linux, kde, gtk

My system is openSUSE 42.1 with Plasma 5.

I have some GTK applications installed as well, and I'm experiencing a rather annoying behaviour from them.

Namely, the tooltips of these apps are almost unreadable, being white text over light grey background, as you can see on the picture

[image]

I can't find where and how to change this setting; only non-KDE apps are affected, and not all of them: Gimp, Inkscape, Filezilla are amongst them, while Firefox, Libreoffice, Handbrake display the tooltips in a readable way.

Comment: Appears to be a more general case of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446089/gimp-tooltips-are-unreadable-white-on-white

Answer (score 4):

The issue is due to a partial override of GTK colors by means of KDE style.

Open `System Settings > Colors`, deselect `Apply colors to non-Qt applications`, restart the GTK application (e.g. Gimp). This breaks the feeling that all applications share the same style but tooltips will be again readable in both Qt and GTK applications.

Comment: Thank-you very much; I have quoted this answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446089/gimp-tooltips-are-unreadable-white-on-white/489316#489316 because it looks better than the answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446090/199532 given there.

Comment: No problem, but please note that you mentioned the wrong comment author in that comment ;)

Comment: Sorry, what  a blunderer! (It was getting too late.) Anyway, it is fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue in Linuc Mint KDE edition. Luckily I found an answer at the ArchLinux wiki:

> To change the colors in GTK2 applications, find the section for
>   tooltips in the `.gtkrc-2.0` file and change it. For GTK3 application
>   two files need to be changed, `gtk.css` and `settings.ini`.

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDE

Comment: I did find `.gtkrc-2.0` (and a `~/.config/gtkrc-2.0`), but it did not have a tooltips section, though it did say `include "/usr/share/themes/Breeze/gtk-2.0/gtkrc"` & `include "/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc"` of which only the former refers to tooltips, with `gtk-color-scheme = "tooltip_fg_color:#fcfcfc"` & `gtk-color-scheme = "tooltip_bg_color:#31363b"`. Would putting those in my own file with updated values have the desired effect?